# Rules for exponential arithmetics

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $e^{it}$ with $t$ real. I can rewrite $t$ as $t=2\pi \tau$:

$ e^{i2\pi\tau} = (e^{i2\pi})^\tau = (1)^\tau = 1 $ for arbitrary $\tau$ or $t$. Where is the mistake in this calculation ? My guess that $(e^x)^y = e^{x\cdot y}$ only applies for real $x$ and $y$, but I don't see why this should be the case despite the example I presented.

Answer (score 3):

You just (re)discovered that $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$ may not hold in the complex.

---

Actually, $a^b$ is not so well defined. By logarithms,

$$a^b=\exp(b \log a)=\exp(b(\log|a|+i\angle a+i2k\pi))$$ where the term $i2k\pi$ introduces an indeterminacy.

---

Back to your example,

$$\log e^{i2\pi}=i2\pi+i2k\pi$$ and

$$(e^{i2\pi})^\tau=\exp(\tau(i2\pi+i2k\pi)),$$ which includes $1$ (for $k=-1$), but not only.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the meaning of $a^z$, it's only that well defined in general for complex numbers.

For other $a$ we will fall into the "rabbit hole" of multi-functions, but we can do it nevertheless. You define $a^z$ otherwise as:

$$a^z = \exp(z \ln a)$$

For clarity I use $\exp$ for the exponential function, ie $\exp z = \sum z^k/k!$ and with $e^z$ I'll use the above definition.

But here we have to realize that $\ln$ is to be considered a multi-function. For each given solution to $e^\omega = a$ also $e^{\omega + 2n\pi j} = a$ is also a solution.

Keeping this in mind the formula still holds, but we have to interpret $1^\tau$ accordingly, that is $\exp(\tau\ln 1)$ where $\ln 1 = 2n\pi j$. This means that $1^\tau = \exp(\tau 2n\pi j)$.

Still the identity $a^{wz} = (a^w)^z$ isn't without complications. By calculation we see that:

$$a^{wz} = \exp{wz \ln a}$$
$$(a^w)^z = \exp(z \ln (a^w)) = \exp(z \ln\exp(w \ln a))$$

Now they would be equal if $\ln\exp(\phi) = \phi$, but it's not that simple. We have instead $\ln\exp\phi = \phi + 2n\pi i$.

Comment: The first line doesn't make a lot of sense. For instance, I could take $a=e^{2}$ and then $a^z=e^{2z}$ would be just as well-defined as $e^z$. (I suspect the correct meaning, in fact, is that $a$ should have argument zero.)

Comment: @Semiclassical I rephrased that a bit, but basically the problem is that in general $a^z$ is defined as $\exp(z\ln a)$ where $\ln a$ in general is not well defined as a function of a complex variable. But even for the case where $a=e$ one could argue that this applies as well - that's why I distinguish between $\exp(z)$ and $e^z$ in the text...